# Fixed vertical navigation menu with dynamically changing menu buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have created a theme for my website with a Fixed vertical navigation menu on the right hand side of the webpage to aid the users to scroll to different sections of the website. Now, these navigation menu buttons help the user in moving to the different sections of the page, but the color of the dots of the menu do not change when we click the dot of a section (or) if we traverse to a section by scrolling up/down. How do you make the color of the dots to change "Dynamically" in the below code? :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body{
background-color:#3E3947;
} 
#cd-vertical-nav {
 position: fixed;
 right: 40px;
 top: 50%;
 bottom: auto;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 z-index: 1;
}
#cd-vertical-nav li {
text-align: right;
list-style:none;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a {
display: inline-block;
/* prevent weird movements on hover when you use a CSS3 transformation -   webkit browsers */
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cd-vertical-nav a:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
 }
 #cd-vertical-nav a span {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
 -ms-transform: scale(0.6);
 -o-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a:hover .cd-label {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav a.is-selected .cd-dot {
  background-color: white;
  }
  #cd-vertical-nav .cd-dot {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d88683;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, background-color 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   }
  #cd-vertical-nav .cd-label {
   position: relative;
   margin-right: 10px;
   padding: .4em .5em;
   color: white;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-size: 0.875rem;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
   -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
   -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
   -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    }


/*********************************RIGHT SIDE    *************************************/

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a data-number="1" href="#section1" class="is-selected">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">Intro</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-number="2" href="#section2" class="">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">About</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-number="3" href="#section3" class="">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">Features</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-number="4" href="#section4" class="">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">Portfolio</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-number="5" href="#section5">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">Pricing</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-number="6" href="#section6">
                <span class="cd-dot"></span>
                <span class="cd-label">Contact</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

    <section id="section1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

    </section>

    <section id="section2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>        

    </section>

    <section id="section3">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>   
    </section>

</body>
```

What JavaScript/Ajax/jQuery/HTML/CSS code do I need to write to make it work?

That is how do we "Dynamically" change the { class="is-selected" } on the code :-

```
<li> <a data-number="2" href="#section2" class=""> <span class="cd-dot">      </span> <span class="cd-label">About</span> </a> </li>
```

etc etc on the other code sections/ nav sections ??? I guess that would solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this for the active class (much like @Sachink suggested):

```
var $navLinks = $('#cd-vertical-nav a');

$navLinks.on('click', function(){
  $navLinks.removeClass('is-selected');
  $(this).addClass('is-selected');
});
```

For the scrolling, you need to watch the scroll position in each of your `<section>`s and when the scrollTop matches a section, set the corresponding menu item's class to `is-selected` like this:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$('section').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset = $this.offset().top;
    var height = $this.outerHeight();

    if (offset + height <= scrollTop || offset >= scrollTop + (windowHeight - (height / 2))) {
      return;
    }

    var selector = '[href="#' + $this.prop('id') + '"]';
    var $menuItem = $navLinks.filter(selector);

    $navLinks.removeClass('is-selected');
    $menuItem.addClass('is-selected');
  });
});
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5w2bkd6k/2/

Comment: Thanks, it works in jsfiddle, but I tried to include the javascript code in the <head> and then <body> separately, but it doesnot work. Where do I need to put this code? Can you include all the code into 1 file and post it? Thanks

Comment: Figured it out, enclose the above JavaScript in a function and call it in the body. Eg :- <script>
            function call(){
                var $navLinks = $('#cd-vertical-nav a');
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

$navLinks.on('click', function(){
  $navLinks.removeClass('is-selected');
  $(this).addClass('is-selected');
});

$('section').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset = $this.offset().top;
    var height = $this.outerHeight();

Comment: if (offset + height <= scrollTop || offset >= scrollTop + (windowHeight - (height / 2))) {
      return;
    }
    
    var selector = '[href="#' + $this.prop('id') + '"]';
    var $menuItem = $navLinks.filter(selector);
      
    $navLinks.removeClass('is-selected');
    $menuItem.addClass('is-selected');
  });
});

            }
        </script>            and call it in the body as shown below:-     </head>
<body onload="call()">
    <nav id="cd-vertical-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <----------Write the remaining code below----------->

Answer (score 3):

**You need to add following jQuery code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('nav li a').click(function(){
            $('nav li a').removeClass('is-selected');
            $(this).addClass('is-selected');
        })
    });
</script>
```

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/5w2bkd6k/1/

**OR**
**I suggest you to use following code for smooth scrolling**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('nav li a').click(function(){
            $('nav li a').removeClass('is-selected');
            $(this).addClass('is-selected');
            event.preventDefault();
            var toGo = $(this).attr('href');
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(toGo).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        })
    });
```

Comment: Will be better if you add any class as a selector instead of `nav li a` .

Comment: Thanks @Sachink , the color of the navigation menu dots changes "ONLY ON" clicking on the dot and not on "SCROLLING". How do you do it for on "Scrolling"?

Comment: @sachintendulkar see right answer of this question, put scrolling JS code in to  `$(document).ready(function(){  // code here });`

Comment: sorry, my bad, I just tried the first code and did not try the second code snippet. It is working, thanks